# enable X-Forwarded-for on oracle cloud private loadbalancer

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, internal-load-balancer, x-forwarded-for

the traffic is accepted at firewall then forwarded to private load-balancer on oracle cloud, the forwarded to internal web servers. the problem is that client IP address at we server is seen as load-balancer IP address. is there a way to add X-Forwarded-for or X-real-IP in order to see actual IP address on internal web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Loadbalancer may be configured to use TCP as opposed to HTTP.  This can cause the header to not be added correctly. Try reconfiguring the loadbalancer to use HTTP